# Why 127.0.0.1:8080/wp jump into 127.0.0.1/wp automatically?

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching

My wordpress was built on 80 port of apache2.
Now i change apache2 configuration file,to make port 80 into 8080,
everytime i input `127.0.0.1:8080/wp`  in the firefox  ,it jump into 127.0.0.1/wp automatically, in order to visit my post,i have to input 
url in the  form of `http://127.0.0.1:8080/wp/?p=1938` ,it will not jump into `http://127.0.0.1/wp/?p=1938`,i wander what result in the jump from `127.0.0.1:8080/wp` into `127.0.0.1/wp` .
it is the cache in apache or cache in firefox?If it is the cache in apache that result in the fact,how to close the cache function in apache2(in debian8)?

In my firefox ,preferences--privary--clear your recent history--cache and cookies , the phenominon vanish.
It is cache or cookie in firefox result in the fact?please tell me why?

Comment: Have you changed your `site_url` and `home_url` in the Admin? Have you flushed / re-saved your permalinks?

Comment: In my firefox ,preferences--privary--clear your recent history--cache and cookies  , the phenominon vanish.why?